# How to get MessageDialog on exiting frame?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I need to know how to get the MessageDialog onto my existing frame, not a pop up frame. I tried just making a buttons for 'ok' and 'cancel' but I couldn't figure out how to get value of the textboxes I had before the ok and cancel.  I got the error of the `TextCtrlInstance.GetValue() is not defined.` Here is the simplified code, which I don't it will help but I will post it anyways.  In this code, a window pops up with ok and cancel but I want it in the 300 by 300 frame.

```
import wx
class oranges(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Stuff',size=(300,300))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        box = wx.MessageDialog(self, 'Cool','title',wx.OK|wx.CANCEL)
        result=box.ShowModal()
        if result==wx.ID_OK:
            print 'ok'
if __name__=='__main__':
    app=wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame=oranges(parent=None,id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Thanks so much in advance! Looking forward to the answers!

Comment: what textboxes? I am confused about what you are trying to do..

Comment: Sorry I didn't include the textboxes in the code because that isn't all that important.  What I want to do is have a ok and cancel messagedialog that is in my existing 300x300 frame. Normally the dialog opens a new window but I need it on my frame.  Thanks!

Comment: you cannot do that ... you need to create a panel and add it to your or subclass the wx.dialog class for your frame (in which case you still have to draw everything) ... the wx.MessageDialog is just a light wrapper around the OS dialog box....

Comment: How can I call the text box info using that?  My main problem I guess is now trying to get the info if my button is pressed.

Comment: I dont understand what info you are talking about ... or which textboxes you are talking about...

Comment: Sorry I am a newbie to wxpython. I am going to make a new question with all the code and try to be more clear.  Thanks and sorry for your confusion!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save user text box input when user clicks 'ok' in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24834010/how-to-save-user-text-box-input-when-user-clicks-ok-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you might want an MDI window:
https://github.com/crankycoder/wxPython-2.9.2.4/blob/master/wxPython/demo/MDIWindows.py
http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/MDIChildFrame.html
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Python/0380__wxPython/MDIframe.htm

It would be easier to just use a custom panel with those buttons and textboxes, like this:

```
import wx

class modalPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.okBtn = wx.Button(self, -1, "OK")
        self.okBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnOkClick)
        sizer.Add(self.okBtn, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def OnOkClick(self, event):
        #do stuff
        pass
        self.Hide()
        self.GetParent().GetParent().stuffPanel.Show()

class normalPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.btn = wx.Button(self, -1, "Show Modal")

        sizer.Add(self.btn, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

class oranges(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1,'Stuff',size=(300,300))

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.stuffPanel = normalPanel(self.panel)
        self.stuffPanel.btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnBtn)

        self.panel2 = modalPanel(self.panel)
        self.panel2.Hide()

        self.sizer.Add(self.stuffPanel, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel2, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.panel.SetSizer(self.sizer)

    def OnBtn(self, event):
        self.stuffPanel.Hide()
        self.panel2.Show()

        self.sizer.Layout()      





if __name__=='__main__':
    app=wx.App(False)
    frame=oranges()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```