# How to save user text box input when user clicks 'ok' in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I am trying to make a pop up window that takes two text inputs and then when the user clicks 'ok', it records the data.  My problem is when I try to define the function of when the 'ok' button is pressed, record the data. I get the `AttributeError: 'apples' object has no attribute 'TextCtrlInstance'`when I press ok.

```
class apples(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Add a stock',size=(300,300))
        frames=wx.Panel(self)
        frames.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMove)
        frames.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.count)
        howmuch=wx.TextCtrl(frames,-1,'#of',pos=(200,173))
        cancel=wx.Button(frames,label='Cancel',pos=(100,250),size=(60,40))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.ca, cancel)
        wx.StaticText(frames,-1,'Enter in valid stock ticker:',pos=(10,50))
        what=wx.TextCtrl(frames,-1,'AAPL',pos=(200,48))
        okbutton = wx.Button(frames,label='OK',pos=(200,250),size=(60,40))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.oker,okbutton)
        wx.StaticText(frames,-1,'Enter in nuber of shares:',pos=(10,175))
    def ca(self,event):
        self.Destroy()
    def oker(self,event):
        #I need the user info when they press ok
        print 'Saved!'
        self.TextCtrlInstance.GetValue()
        self.Destroy()
    def OnMove(self,event):
        pass 
    def count(self,event):
        pass
if __name__ =='__main__':
    apps = wx.PySimpleApp()
    windows = apples(parent=None,id=-1)
    windows.Show()
    apps.MainLoop()
```

I hope this is enough to give me a solution! Thanks and I look forward to the answers!

Comment: I'm not familliar with wx, but I don't see where `TextCtrlInstance` has been defined.

Comment: There is an usage in Python that _class name_ have a Capital initial, whereas _instance name_ starts with a lower case. Like all coding convention this is subject to debate. However, may I suggest you to stick with that usage for now, as this might help you to distinguishes between _classes_ and _objects_ in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An educated *guess* as I didn't run your code:

```
def __init__(self,parent,id):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Add a stock',size=(300,300))
    self.frames=wx.Panel(self)
    self.frames.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMove)
    self.frames.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.count)
    self.howmuch=wx.TextCtrl(frames,-1,'#of',pos=(200,173))
    self.cancel=wx.Button(frames,label='Cancel',pos=(100,250),size=(60,40))
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.ca, cancel)
    wx.StaticText(frames,-1,'Enter in valid stock ticker:',pos=(10,50))
    self.what=wx.TextCtrl(frames,-1,'AAPL',pos=(200,48))
    self.okbutton = wx.Button(frames,label='OK',pos=(200,250),size=(60,40))
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.oker,okbutton)
    wx.StaticText(frames,-1,'Enter in nuber of shares:',pos=(10,175))

[...]

def oker(self,event):
    qty = self.howmuch.GetValue()
    what = self.what.GetValue()
    print "Saved", qty, "of", what
```

You need to store your various widget as *instance* variables if you need to access them from other methods of the same object. In Python, this is written `self.varname = ....`. Usually from the `__init__` special method. You probably missed a bunch of them (maybe not all those I've add -- YMMV)

Then, [GetValue](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.TextCtrl-class.htmlhttp://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.TextCtrl-class.html) is a method of the TextCtrl class. In order to use it, it has to be invoked on an *instance* of that class.

Given your code, the only two (visible) instances of `TextCtrl` are "`self.howmuch`" and "`self.what`".

Comment: This didn't work as I got a `AttributeError: 'apples' object has no attribute 'howmuch'` error.  It seems like I somehow have to get the __init__ values?

Comment: in the __init__ function do `self.what=...`  instead of `what=...`

Comment: Thank you @Dave for your comment: I don't know how I could have missed that o_O !

Comment: Thanks to both of you!  I can know do other things with my basic program!!